# Where is the epiphany browser history?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, web-browsers, logfiles

I am running a Epiphany on Raspberry Pi 2 and I would like to check the browser history.

Where is the epiphany browser log?

Do I Have to enable it somewhere?

If doesn't exist, how can I create it?

Comment: from what I can tell, it is enabled by default, maybe you disabled it by going to 'Preferences -> Privacy'?

Comment: I am running all from console.

Comment: have you searched in /usr/?

Comment: I found at /home/pi/.config/ephy-history.db I trying to open it yet with sqlite3

Comment: Where you able to recover the history from that db file?

Comment: Yes. I got the browser history from that file. Using sqlite3 I was able to query on the file. Now I am trying to do the query on a bash script file.